# How to add TAG to every marker and set the UniqueId on every marker separatly

Tags: android, json, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

> How to add TAG to every marker and set the UniqueId on every marker.
>   Uniqueid's of every marker received from the server
>   Here is DoInBackgroung Code please help me

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
               // ModelClass s = LoganSquare.parse(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ModelClass.class);
                ModelClass modelClass = new Gson().fromJson(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ModelClass.class);


                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(modelClass.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(modelClass.getLongitude())); // Use your server's methods
                latLngList.add(latLng);
```

> Here is code to add marker

```
private void AddPointer() {
try {

    if (marker != null) {
        mMap.clear();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remove", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    for (LatLng object : latLngList)

        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));

    System.out.println(marker.getPosition() + "  Marker position.......");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // mMap.clear();
}
 }
```

> OnpostExecute code where i add the Marker that received from the server in this time i have two markers on server with its uniqueId's

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // dialog.cancel();
    // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receicve data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (result == false) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    AddPointer();

}
```

> Here is Model Class

```
 public class ModelClass {

     @SerializedName("longi")
   public String longitudeServer;

    @SerializedName("lati")
    public String latitudeServer;

     @SerializedName("uniqueid")
      public String uniqueidSserver;

      public ModelClass(){
      }

      public String getLongitude(){
        return longitudeServer;
      }



      public String getLatitude(){
         return latitudeServer;
     }


            public String getUniqueId(){
          return uniqueidSserver;
      }

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try this you can set diffrent marker and give uniqueid or name


    // Prepare Model Class like this way

    public class LocationDetail
    {
    public String longitudeServer;
    public String latitudeServer;
    public String uniqueidSserver;

    public String getLongitudeServer() {
        return longitudeServer;
    }

    public void setLongitudeServer(String longitudeServer) {
        this.longitudeServer = longitudeServer;
    }

    public String getLatitudeServer() {
        return latitudeServer;
    }

    public void setLatitudeServer(String latitudeServer) {
        this.latitudeServer = latitudeServer;
    }

    public String getUniqueidSserver() {
        return uniqueidSserver;
    }

    public void setUniqueidSserver(String uniqueidSserver) {
        this.uniqueidSserver = uniqueidSserver;
    }
}



  //Prepare the arraylist like this

try
    {
        LocationDetail modelclass;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<LocationDetail> locationDetails = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONArray jsonArray = ""; // initilise your server data
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            modelclass = new LocationDetail();
            modelclass.setLongitudeServer(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject
                    .getString("Latitude").toString()));
            modelclass.setLatitudeServer(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject
                    .getString("Longitude").toString()));
            modelclass.setUniqueidSserver(jsonObject.getString(
                    "UniqueId").toString());
            list.add(modelclass);
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





    //Now pass above Arraylist to method    
    private void showMap(ArrayList<Reach_Us> list) {
                double latitude = 0;
                double longitude = 0;
                try {

                    // Loading map
                    initilizeMap();
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                    // Enable / Disable zooming controls
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                    // Enable / Disable my location button
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

                    // Enable / Disable Compass icon
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

                    // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

                    // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

                    // lets place some 10 random markers
                    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {

                        latitude = list.get(i).getLatitude();
                        longitude = list.get(i).getLongitude();

                        // Adding a marker
                        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(
                                        new LatLng(list.get(i).getLatitude(), list
                                                .get(i).getLongitude()))

                                .title(i + ":"
                                        + list.get(i).getUniqueidSserver().toString());

                        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

                        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(new LatLng(list.get(i).getLatitude(), list
                                        .get(i).getLongitude())).zoom(15).build();

                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: No i have have no idea how many markers it may b 10 or 100 give me the generic solution..

Comment: You can set one marker and remove all other marker with condition so it generic

Comment: hmmm good bt how to set unique id on every marker unique id's are received from server every longi and lati marker have unique id please tell me how to set unique id on every marker

Comment: In your Model Class you generate only getter method but you should generate the setter method also and set all value and then generate the array list and then pass in above method

Comment: ok bt please write the code how to implement i understand better

Comment: Hi Pravin Fofariya i hope you are fine i face error on 
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(list.get(i).getLatitudeServer()), list.get(i).getLongitudeServer())).zoom(15).build();

it shows LatLnd Double Double cannot be applied to Double

Comment: use method name given in model class getLongitudeServer(),getUniqueidSserver(),getUniqueidSserver()

Comment: NOW i face error on CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(list.get(i).getLatitudeServer()), list.get(i).getLongitudeServer())).zoom(15).build(); it shows LatLnd Double Double cannot be applied to Double –

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108685/discussion-between-pravin-fofariya-and-ahmad).

Answer (score 0):

Pravin i do like this.

```
 protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(data);

                latLngList.clear();

                try {
                    LocationDetail modelclass;
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    ArrayList<LocationDetail> locationDetails = new ArrayList<>();

                    // JSONArray jsonArray = ""; // initilise your server data
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        modelclass = new LocationDetail();
                        modelclass.setLongitudeServer(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString("Latitude").toString()));
                        modelclass.setLatitudeServer(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString("Longitude").toString()));
                        modelclass.setUniqueidSserver(jsonObject.getString("UniqueId").toString());

                        list.add(modelclass);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return true;

            }
```

> and also

```
 private void showMap(ArrayList<LocationDetail> list) {
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;
    try {

        // Loading map
        initMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming controls
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable my location button
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Compass icon
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        // lets place some 10 random markers
        for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {

            latitude = list.get(i).getLatitudeServer();
            longitude = list.get(i).getLongitudeServer();

            // Adding a marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(list.get(i).getLatitudeServer(), list
                                    .get(i).getLongitudeServer()))

                    .title(i + ":"
                            + list.get(i).getUniqueidSserver().toString());

            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

            mMap.addMarker(marker);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(list.get(i).getLatitudeServer()), list.get(i).getLongitudeServer())).zoom(15).build();

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> And also in

```
     public class LocationDetail
 {
public double longitudeServer;
public double latitudeServer;
public String uniqueidSserver;

public double getLongitudeServer() {
    return longitudeServer;
}

public void setLongitudeServer(double longitudeServer) {
    this.longitudeServer = longitudeServer;
}

public double getLatitudeServer() {
    return latitudeServer;
}

public void setLatitudeServer(double latitudeServer) {
    this.latitudeServer = latitudeServer;
}

public String getUniqueidSserver() {
    return uniqueidSserver;
}

public void setUniqueidSserver(String uniqueidSserver) {
    this.uniqueidSserver = uniqueidSserver;
}
```

}

> But error in this line

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(list.get(i).getLatitudeServer()), list.get(i).getLongitudeServer())).zoom(15).build(); it shows LatLnd Double Double cannot be applied to Double